# Trigger change event of element created using knockout js through console

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Below is inspect element part of combobox.

```
<select id="ddl-fund" aria-label="Funds" tabindex="0" data-bind="options: FundsAvailable, optionsText: 'Value', optionsValue: 'Key', value: SelectedFund, event:{ change: onSelectedFund}"> 
   <option value="413">International Equity Portfolio</option>
   <option value="723">International Equity Fund</option>
   <option value="724">International Select Fund</option>
</select>
```

I want to fire change event from console.
I have changed value of combobox using below script.

```
$('#ddl-fund').find('option')[1].selected=true;
```

If I call change event using following script, It's not working:

```
$('#ddl-fund').trigger('change');
```

Comment: `$('#ddl-fund').trigger('change');` will work (assuming the event handler was bound using jQuery). If it wasn't bound using jQuery then you'll need to trigger the event directly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#triggering_built-in_events

Comment: It's work with other elements but for this element without event handler, it's using knockout's change event binding.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `ko.dataFor('#ddl-fund')` to get the viewmodel that the select element is bound to.  Then it should just be a matter to execute the `onSelectFund` assuming that it is part of the found viewmodel.

[Knockoutjs - Using unobtrusive event handlers](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html)